# Change Xdebug setting to 4 tabs instead of 2 tabs

Tags: php, xdebug

> Here as you can see, var_dump renders the nested arrays with 2 tabs,
>   but I need 4 tabs indenting.

```
object(app\models\Category)[83]
  private '_attributes' (yii\db\BaseActiveRecord) => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => int 694
      'title' => string 'Запчасти Mac' (length=20)
      'parent' => int 685
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is possible. Here is the documentation: https://xdebug.org/docs/display